# Can't find the intel virtulization technology inside BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi

I am having the Gigabyte UEFI dual bios. I've watched some youtube videos of people having the same BIOS as me and they have their Intel virtulization technology under the Full Screen Logo show, I don't.

Here is a picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8o5Z.jpg)

I need to enable this so I can use the AVD manager in android studio

Comment: Do not spam with irrelevant tags.

Comment: Are you sure your motherboard supports virtualization? What is its model?

Comment: Look under security in Bios

Comment: To be honest I didn't even cosider my motherboard not supporting virtualization nor do I know how to check if it does. Now that I think about it thats probably the case. If so, what would be my options when developing android applications? I will go and check if my motherboard supports it right away, thank you!

Comment: Okay, I checked it and my computer supports hyper-v virtualization.

Comment: what cpu do you have?